# Close HTML tags in truncated string

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have an ASP.NET page that displays a number of blog posts one after another.  I don’t want to print the whole blog posts but only a set number of characters with a Read More link. Every post is saved as html in database from where it gets loaded. I currently strip all the html tags off from the post and display the set number of characters (e.g first 300) but I eventually lose all the styling. If I don’t strip the tags off then the truncated post gets various unclosed html tags which break the page especially on IE. The blog posts are entered through a different system of which I don’t have any control over. To overcome this issue, I have written a method that takes the html in a string adds all opening tags to an array list and as soon as a tag is closed removes it from the end of the array list so at the end the array list is only left with opening tags that have not closed. I check for those tags and replace each tag with its closing tag. Then I add all these closing tags to a string and append the string to the actual html string. When adding opening tags to the string I ignore all tags that include /> to avoid self closing tags. This is doing the job for me but my method is prone to bugs as html string is not predictable. Is there a better way around this issue ?

Comment: There could be a better way, yes.  The problem is, without seeing your code, how could we suggest this 'better way'?

Comment: I would suggest that you also take out the length of the strings of the html tags from your 300 character count as well. If a person put a lot of html at the beginning, then you could end up with an empty display.

Comment: @Brian Thanks but I am looking for a different approach to what I am already doing. That's why I have not provided the code and have explained my way of doing it the question so that someone can answer with a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to manipulate the blog post as raw html, assuming there is a consistent structure to the blog posts, extract the content of the blog post and reformat it as necessary.

For instance, if the blog is formatted like this,

```
<blog>
  <title>The blog title</title>
  <content>
    A bunch of content
  </content>
</blog>
```

then parse the blog into a POCO

```
public class Blog
{
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

then manipulate the content and redisplay it as you want to.

```
<div class="blog-summary">
  <h1>@Model.Title</h1>
  <p>
    @Model.Content.Substring(0, 300)
  </p>
</div>
```

That way you are only taking a sub string of the content of the blog, not the markup.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately The blog post doesn't have a consistent structure. The posts are entered through a WYSIWYG editor so they don't follow a structure and the whole blog post including is saved as raw html in the database. Also, the blog post need to display exactly as its entered on WYSIWYG and your way of doing this will change its styling.